# iOS 11 UITableViewCell above viewForHeaderInSection view after deleting

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, ios11

I have simple UITableViewController.

View for header. Which inits from xib.
And single type of cell.

After deleting cell with swipe, cell which above deleted one become visible above HeaderView, when other cells just hides below HeaderView as it should be.

If something above not clear - ask.

Video: https://youtu.be/aX-iPnM3q4Q

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution.

```
func deleteItem(from indexPath: IndexPath, tableView: UITableView) {
    cellsData.remove(at: indexPath.row)
    CATransaction.begin()
    tableView.beginUpdates()
    CATransaction.setCompletionBlock {
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
    tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .left)
    tableView.endUpdates()
    CATransaction.commit()
}
```

tableView.reloadData() do the thing that fixing appearing cell above the headerView, but kills animation. So if you don't care about animation you can add only reloadData().

Answer (score 0):

I think this should solve it:

```
tableView.sendSubview(toFront: tableView.headerView(forSection: 0)!)
```

(assuming you have only 1 section)

You can set this after deleting the cell, for example in `commitEditingStyle`.

Comment: That was first thing I tryed. Didn't help, unfortunately.